# Test if two dates are consecutive days

Tags: function, date, julia

In Julia, how can I test if two dates are consecutive days?

For instance:

```
using Dates
is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), == DateTime(2013,7,2,12,30) # true
is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), == DateTime(2013,6,29,12,30) # false
```

Do I have to implement `is_consecutive` manually or is there a Julia function for comparing two dates?

What if I would like to know if two different DateTimes are consecutive for the `hours`, the `seconds` etc.

Comment: Something like `DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30) + Day(1) == DateTime(2013,7,2,12,30)`?

Comment: How do you expect two `DateTime` structs with different time components to compare? Do you expect `is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), DateTime(2013,7,2,12,31))` to equal `true` or `false`? How about `is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), DateTime(2013,7,2,12,29))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the difference between two Dates.

However, in case of DateTime and two different times each day, one needs to floor() the timestamp. round() does not work as it rounds to the nearest day, so dt1 could be floored and dt2 ceiled.

In case a commutative behavior is wanted, also take the absolute value of the difference.

```
using Dates

function is_consecutive_day(dt1::DateTime, dt2::DateTime)
    #floor() is necessary in case dt1 or dt2 are not exactly 86400000 milliseconds apart
    #take abs() to ensure that function is commutative
    diff = abs(floor(dt1, Day) - floor(dt2, Day))
    return diff == Day(1)
end
```

Comment: Your answer is best as more generic :)

Answer (score 3):

Just compare the differences

```
using Dates

function is_consecutive(date1::DateTime, date2::DateTime)
    difference = date2 - date1
    return difference == Day(1)
end

print(is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), DateTime(2013,7,2,12,30))) # true
print(is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30), DateTime(2013,6,30,12,30))) # false
print(is_consecutive(DateTime(2013,6,30,12,30), DateTime(2013,7,1,12,30))) # true
```